# Pngcrush libpng error: Not enough image

Tags: ios, libpng, pngcrush

This is the error Message in Xcode:
While checking alphas in `/Path/image@2x.png` `pngcrush` caught `libpng error:   Not enough image dCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure`

But the Application is running fine even with this error. Even the image is loading on the iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0

I tried removing the image and adding it again. Also tried saving it into png from Preview.

Comment: Please confirm that the error is indeed "Not enough image dCommand".
Does it say /Path/image@2x.png or did you replace the actual path with Path?

Comment: Yeah I replaced the Actual Path. The error says "Not enough image dCommand".

Comment: The string "Command" doesn't appear anywhere in my copy of pngcrush nor is it anywhere in libpng.  I guess it is somewhere in Apple's modified pngcrush, but that's closed source so I can't debug it.

Comment: Do you still need help with the issue?

Comment: Hi Petur I'd Appreciate it. Also I thank all of you guys for the responses. There are not duplicate images in the project and the images are not interlaced. My Image size is of 1x100 pixel. Has the image width got anything to do with this ?

Answer (score 11):

libpng is an open source project, the source code is available here: [Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/)

I searched the source code for the error you mentioned, *Not enough image dCommand*. The closest match i could find was *Not enough image data*, from *pngrutil.c*

A quick google of *Not enough image data* gives this solution from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287600/build-app-with-xcode-4-it-always-show-some-error-about-png-image)

> Found it!!
>
> You have to save your PNG files as NOT INTERLACED. Try to open the
>   file in photoshop (or similar), save as, and select "Not interlaced".
>
> It is working in my case
>
> hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Im my case because of redundancy of images it was happening so I deleted all those images which ever was causing error.And Error was gone...!

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this error is when you manually change extension of `.jpg` image as `.png`. It normally works fine, But when you will try to run on device, such errors are raised. So re-save your image in **png format (non interlaced)**.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it would be a problem on the image it self and you will need to open it in preview and reexport it again as PNG.

Better and a fast solution use this App called "imageoptim" it will compress the images and solve PNGcrushs
http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html

Comment: Yeah I already tried ImageOptim, but the error remains as it is.

Answer (score 0):

That solved my problem. In my case, it was repeated png files name.

[Not a PNG filCommand copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679710/not-a-png-filcommand-copypng-emitted-errors-but-did-not-return-a-nonzero-exit-co)