# How do i fix this CopyPNG File error?

Tags: ios, xcode

While reading */Users/user/Desktop/AppProject/PruebaApp/Logo*  *Retina.png*

`pngcrush` caught libpng error:

> Read Er Could not find file:
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PruebaApp-cblepoaxbqzyopcbcswwqjtftyon/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MaderoAPP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MaderoAPP.app/Logo
>   Retina.png

Command

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng
>   emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate
>   failure

Im getting these errors while archiving project, at the end it does archive but i want to get rid of it. I had trouble with the app before and i read that i should delete the DerivedData/(myproject)folder so i did. and apparently it is trying to look for the images in that folder how do i fix this??? Help!

Comment: Is this a specific PNG? Try creating it again, maybe it's an encoding issue

Comment: Ok I have found the folder it does exist but the problem is that when i go into /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PruebaApp-cblepoaxbqzyopcbcswwqjtftyon/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MaderoAPP/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MaderoAPP.app/Logo Retina.png


it only goes to: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PruebaApp-cblepoaxbqzyopcbcswwqjtftyon/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MaderoAPP

Comment: no nevermind it didnt work :/

Comment: try: delete the PNG from the app and re-add it.

Comment: already did that and still nothing

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try first by Hard Cleaning your project **`CMD+OPTION+SHIFT+K`**, If problem exists apply following method,

`Build Phases` -> `Copy Bundle Resources`, Any fileName is red color?

**Or**

Convert Logo Retina.png or Create it again, maybe it's an encoding\format issue.

**Or**

Rename "Logo Retina.png" to "LogoRetina.png".

~Good luck~

Comment: Thanks I opened the Logo Retina.png in an image editor and saved it as a new file and that work great!

Comment: for me it worked also . I opened with paintbrush , save as , let the same name and after click replace .

Comment: Opening in Preview and re-saving worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yey, first one helped me. It wasn't in a red color but there I could finally totally delete the image file that I wanted to have deleted and stop this error from popping up. Thanks!!

Comment: The format was the case for me. Saved it with GIMP. After re-exporting with Preview, worked No problemo! Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

It also happens when you have multiple images with the same name in **TARGET->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources**. To resolve it -

1. Search for the image name that you are getting an error for in **Build
   Phases** search bar at the top.
2. If you get multiple results in **Copy Bundle Resources** for the search query, just remove others from it by clicking on "-" sign. Make sure you have same images for the multiple results. If not you have to rename the actual files of other entries.
3. Just compile your code. You are good to go.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 9):

Just open image in Preview app and export it as png file. Replace old image with new in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I have had this problem intermittantly many times and clean then rebuild has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answers here are either not useful at all or quite complicated I want to add mine:

The error means that Xcode can not find the file, whether it is in the project's folder or not.

- If you still need that image, what you can do is to open a *Finder* view and navigate to your project. Drag the file Xcode was complaining about into the project an **uncheck 'Copy to folder'**.
- if you do not need the file anymore, on the left side of Xcode, find the file, it will be shown in red, simply tap on it and then **delete** / **backspace**

Hope that helps some people :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue copy the Image name. Then  Filter it (**Build Phases -> Filter textfield**). Finally I removed it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you are not naming the images with only a number like "0.png" I change it to "tuts0.png" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and honestly I think it was being caused by another error. I had an issue with my Crashlytics framework and I'm convinced it was effect some unassociated pngs with the `copypng` error. I replaced the `Crashlytics.framework` with a fresh version and viola, all errors were gone.

Don't ask me how this works, I'm just posting this in case someone else can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix this problem. So i delete and reinstalled xcode, this helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reverting to my old product name (in "Build settings"). Seems that the new product name confused the images path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with resources. The problem was that I have copied target from another one and just forget to uncheck checkbox at target membership window.

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem and this solution is working form me 
you need to remove any reference for that image

> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

after that clean and build and problem will be fixed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally deleted the file from the location which was linked to x-code project. I had **not copied** the file in my xcode project but just the path. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with pngcrush /libpng crashing with PNGs (checksum errors / freeing object that have been freed etc). These could be reproduced on the command line so I recreated the PNGs, even converted them to other formats then back but the errors persisted. In my case Xcode then rejected the resulting archive for not having iPhone 5 support (as pngcrush killed the Default-568h@2x.png image). The above fix resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with this error while building **Cordova app**.
 Please keep the following point in consideration as it may lead to this error.

- The images should be tagged as "resource-file" and not as "source-file" in plugin.xml of your Cordova plugin as the former includes the images in "Copy Bundle Resources" (under Build Phase) and the latter to "Compile Sources" of your equivalent xcode project of cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

If non of above answers can fix your problem, try look into Xcode project where you reference your image file, I happened to referenced twice to the same png file. Once I delete one the reference, it worked. The error went away. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens when you have multiple images with the same name in TARGET->Build Phases->**Copy Bundle Resources**. To resolve it -

Search for the image name that you are getting an error for in Build Phases search bar at the top.
If you get multiple results in Copy Bundle Resources for the search query, just remove others from it by clicking on "-" sign. Make sure you have same images for the multiple results. If not you have to rename the actual files of other entries.

clean cmd+option+shift+k and Build Project...
work well for me....