# Compiling issue with imported images Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am putting my finishing touches on my application, and in doing that I created a launch image and some templates in light room. I have run the application through the simulator to test it out first, then went to test on my IOS Device through Xcode, which I have been doing the whole time through this application. It compiles and runs great through the simulator, but when I try and run it through my phone it gives me 13 issues. All of them are the same:

```
/CliffHanger/CliffHanger v5/CliffHanger v4.0/NoStarImage.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
Not a PNG file..

Could not find file: Xcode/DerivedData/CliffHanger_v4.0-
aqfzdgffvepdrdburawodkfmfqym/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CliffHanger v4.0.app/NoStarImage.png
Command 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng 
emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

I know this seems like a straight forward error, basically saying it is not a PNG file, but it is a PNG file.... This is why it is baffling me.....

Comment: Maybe worth looking at some of the suggestions in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387671/ipad-png-crush-error

Comment: Have you tried opening it in something like Photoshop and saving it out again as a PNG? Also, make sure that your resources are also ticked to be included in the target.

Comment: Did you lookup the exit code? What was it and it's description?

Comment: @Goodsum I went to get info and checked the extension there

Comment: If you fixed it, post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I tried earlier, but wouldn't allow me. Hadn't been long enough

Comment: @user3669844 Just because the extension says it's a PNG doesn't mean that it actually is a correct PNG. That's why it would be a good idea to open it in an Editor and save it out as a new image.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I went back and re-saved all of my images doing this : Open up image with Preview -> File > Export > Format change to PNG