# Why are my files getting corrupted on Xcode 4.5.2?

Tags: xcode

After doing a clean, I got some `CopyPNGFile` and `Copy Plist File` errors. The corresponding files were corrupted - I couldn't open them with any program (Xcode, Preview, Photoshop...)

Solutions at [Build app with Xcode 4 - it always show some error about PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287600/build-app-with-xcode-4-it-always-show-some-error-about-png-image) didn't help, since absolutely nothing I try can open those files.

My concern right now isn't about fixing those errors though. I'm under the impression that my files are **actively getting corrupted**. I had like four corrupted files yesterday, and today, after doing a new clean, I have like nine.

What might be causing this corruption? Is there any other way to fix the files without opening them (because it seems I can't open them in any way)?

Comment: Does your SCM mark the files as changed? Do you work within Dropbox?

Comment: @mbogh: I honestly don't know what SCM is. I'm not working with dropbox. But that reminds me that I've transfered my project a few times using a external harddrive to other machines. I suppose this could've corrupted my files... twice...

Comment: SCM - Source code management, so git, svn etc.

Comment: @mbogh: I don't use any SCM. It is a really simple project.