# XCode App Icon error

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I made PNG 58×58 image named `myIcon@2x.png` and set to app icon.
When build by simulator, the app correctly run.
But when real machine, the app outputs error
 
with message `Failed to write PNG data for the app icon set from "AppIcon appiconse.../test.app/AppIcon29×29@2x.png`
Why do such error occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to find answer here - [Build app with Xcode 4 - it always show some error about PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287600/build-app-with-xcode-4-it-always-show-some-error-about-png-image)

There is solution:

You have to save your PNG files as NOT INTERLACED. Try to open the file in photoshop (or similar), save as, and select "Not interlaced".

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use simulator with **retina** display, but device with **non-retina** display.
Icon with size **58×58** is used for iPhone Settings/Spotlight, iPad Settings for **retina** display.
Icon with size **29×29** is used for the same aims but for **non-retina** display.

1. Actually you need add icon with size **29×29**.
2. If this icon exists in your project then check if it is really uses **PNG** format.

Answer (score 0):

The 58 x 58 size is for the Settings icon, not the app icon. Look at the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html) for details

App icon (required for all apps) 120 x 120, 152 x 152, 76 x 76

Settings icon (recommended) 58 x 58, 29 x 29